# Syntax error on token ">>", Expression expected after this token

Tags: javafx, cell, tablecolumn

I'm getting *Syntax error on token “>>”, Expression expected after this token* when calling `setCellFactory` below but do not understand why.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableVieww extends Application {

    private static TableView<TableData> table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Stage s = primaryStage;
        s.setTitle("The Title");

        TableColumn<TableData, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("String");
        column1.setMinWidth(150); 
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, String>("s"));
        column1.setEditable(true);
        column1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        column1.setOnEditCommit(e -> {

        });


        TableColumn<TableData, Double> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Double");
        column2.setMinWidth(50);
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, Double>("d"));
        column2.setEditable(true);
        // Error within this line (The line below)
        column2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        column2.setOnEditCommit(e -> {

        });


        // set up a table
        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getData()); 
        table.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2);
        table.setEditable(true);

        // setting up a layout
        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().add(table);

        // Setting up a scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 500, 200);
        s.setScene(scene);
        s.show();
    }



    private static ObservableList<TableData> getData(){
        ObservableList<TableData> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
        TableVieww view = new TableVieww();
        list.add(view.new TableData("BlaBlaBla", 10));
        list.add(view.new TableData("TraTraTra", 5.1));
        return list;
    }

    public class TableData{

        double d;
        String s;

        public TableData(String s, double d) {
            this.d = d;
            this.s = s;
        }

        public double getD() {
            return d;
        }

        public void setD(double d) {
            this.d = d;
        }

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }


    }



}
```

What is wrong?  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: cleanup for clarity & readability

Comment: Your code is not executable, you are using classes that I do not have, try and see if you can narrow the problem down to a small class that I can run.

Answer (score 1):

This is not entirely flawless, but it works. You will probaly need to adjust it too fit your needs a lot, but...it works.

```
public class SpinnerTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {
    private Spinner spinner;
    private String text;

    public SpinnerTableCell(int min, int max) {
        this.spinner = new Spinner(min, max, 0.0);
        spinner.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldBoolean, newBoolean)->{
            if(!newBoolean){
                setText(spinner.getValue().toString());
                text = getText();
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public void startEdit() {
        if (this.isEditable() && this.getTableView().isEditable() && this.getTableColumn().isEditable()) {
            super.startEdit();
            if (this.isEditing()) {
                setText("");
                setGraphic(spinner);
            }

        }
    }

    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(text);
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? "" : item.toString());
        spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(empty ? 0.0 : item);
    }
}
```

You can set the factory with `tableCell.setCellFactory((e)->new SpinnerTableCell(min, max));`

Comment: Didn't fixed the error, in fact new error appeared: Syntax error on token ",", delete this token

Comment: In this way eclipse says that i need to add one more method of TableCell<Customer, Double>, that's not a problem but i have those two methods and they need to return something, so what i should put for a return ? Isn't there a less complicated way to do this stuff ? For String column it works with stateColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

Comment: Use the one Eclipse generated, mine must have been incorrect.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are just displaying a `Double`, then I do not believe you even need the `TableColumn.setCellFactory()` call.

Comment: Try `TableColumn.setEditable(true)`.

Comment: Then I don't think you need the `TableColumn.setCellFactory(...)`, have you tried running it without it?

Comment: I did, without setCellFactory nothing happens on click